# Trigger is preventing an insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger running on my Asterisk "cel" table with a bunch of conditions. It appears that this condition prevents the record I am trying to catch from being inserted into the "cel" table.

Here is the trigger's condition:

`IF (NEW.eventtype = 'CHAN_START' AND CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.cid_num) > 4 AND NEW.cid_ani = '' AND NEW.cid_rdnis = '' AND NEW.cid_dnid = '' AND CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.exten) > 4) THEN
    INSERT INTO mem_callers VALUES (NEW.linkedid, NEW.eventtype, NEW.cid_num, NEW.exten, NEW.exten, NEW.eventtime);
END IF;`

This is supposed to insert a record in my "mem_callers" table, but with this condition in my trigger, the "CHAN_START" record is never inserted into the "cel" table.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: More info:
I have my trigger set on AFTER new INSERT on the cel table.

Comment: Your condition isn't passing. As for why - insufficient information. Inspect the data you're sending through the query then check which one doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: I would understand if my query did not satisfy the condition, it would not write into the "mem_callers" table, but why would it prevent the insert from happening on the "cel" table, on which I am running the trigger from?
Removing that condition from my trigger allows "CHAN_START" records to be written to "cel" table again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears to be misbehaving because I'm doing something stupid.

I added another column to the "mem_callers" table earlier and my INSERT statement in that condition did not include a value for the new column.
Once I've added a value both tables inserted the correct records.